# neo4j/cypher: Find all nodes adjacent to all nodes in some set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a node, s, adjacent to a set, C, of >1 nodes of some label. I want to find all nodes that are also adjacent to every element in C.

More generally:

- how does one define sets or groups in cypher?
- how does one find nodes that are adjacent to all the nodes in a set?

Is this even doable in cypher?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely, this is doable in cypher.  Here is an example.

```
// start with finding the start node 's' and the adjacent nodes
match (s:Node {name: 's'} )-[:ADJ]->(C:Node)
// match only the adjacent nodes that have 'set C'
where C.set = 'C'
// pass C onto the remainder of the query
with s,C
// match the nodes that are adjacent to the nodes in 'set C'
match C-[:ADJ]->(adjacent)
// return all of the nodes in set C and a collection of the nodes
// adjacent to the set C nodes
return s.name, C.name, collect(adjacent.name)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for replying. Unfortunately, this query seems to return all nodes adjacent to *any* element of C. What I would like is to find nodes adjacent to *all* elements of C.

Comment: Your reply has helped me understand the with statement and flow of data in cypher much better, however, so thanks again for that :)

Comment: This finds all of the elements in C and then finds all of the nodes that are adjacent to each element of C.  It only looks for outbound adjacent nodes but that is easily changed by removing the arrow from the relationship. Is it that you want all of the nodes that are adjacent to the set C returned as a single collection?

Comment: Hi @dave-bennet, as far as I can tell, your code finds all the elements in C and then finds all nodes that are adjacent to any node in C.

Comment: Each of the nodes I'd like to find are adjacent to *every* node in C.